# Custom Paging for ASP.Net MVC Kendo Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC Kendo Grid as follows.  It is working fine with default paging.

Now, I want to do custom paging. In the controller action we need to know the current page index. Also it should set the “total” count for the grid. [The actual data source will have only 2 records at a time even if there are 100 records in the database. So the grid must know the total number of records in database using “total” attribute.]

The query should return only 2 records from the database at a time.

How can we do this custom server paging using the MVC wrapper for Kendo Grid?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 

    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoUIMvcSample.Models.Sample>()    
    .Name("ssgrid222")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(p => p.SampleDescription).Filterable(false).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.SampleCode).Filterable(false).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.SampleItems).Filterable(false).Width(100);
    })
    .AutoBind(false)
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(2)
        .Read(read => read.Action("Orders_Read", "Sample")
)
     )
  )
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Orders_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {

            int currentPageNumber = request.Page;
            return Json(GetOrders().ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
```

Comment: I think if you bring back IQueryable, Kendo will handle and make the appropriate query to database. don't run the query before passing data to Kendo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is defined in the [kendo site](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/custom-binding)

**CONTROLLER CODE**

```
    //Paging and Sorting
    int currentPage = request.Page;
    int pageSize = request.PageSize;
    string sortDirection = "ASC";
    string sortField = "UpdatedDateTime";

    if (request.Sorts != null && request.Sorts.Count > 0)
    {
        sortField = request.Sorts[0].Member;
        sortDirection = request.Sorts[0].SortDirection.ToString();
    }

//Setting the TOTAL
var result = new DataSourceResult()
{
    Data = orders, 
    Total = total // Total number of records
};

return Json(result);
```

**VIEW**

```
      <div class="GridSearch">

                @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MVC.Models.TransactionHistoryModel>()
    .Name("TransactionHistroyGrid")
     .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(25)
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .Read(read => read
            .Action("TransactionHistorySearch_Read", "TransactionHistoryResults")
            .Data("additionalData")
            )
     )
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.UserId).Filterable(false).Width(40).Title("Userid");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Reviewed).Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input id='checkbox'  class='chkbx' type='checkbox' />").Filterable(false).Width(30).Title("Reviewed");
        columns.Bound(p => p.CreatedOnEnd).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Filterable(false).Width(50).Title("Created On");
        columns.Bound(p => p.UpdatedOnEnd).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Filterable(false).Width(50).Title("Updated On");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Comment).Filterable(false).Width(50).Title("Comment");
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:325px;" })

  )
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a custom paging solution we have implemented for Kendo ListView. With minor modification it should work for the grid.  The solution consists of a custom DataSoure Object and a custom JSonResult class.

The custom data source:

```
public class MyDataSource
{
    public object AggregateResults { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
    public object Errors { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}
```

The custom ActionResult:

```
public class JsonNetResult : ActionResult
{
    public Encoding ContentEncoding { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }

    public JsonSerializerSettings SerializerSettings { get; set; }
    public Formatting Formatting { get; set; }

    public JsonNetResult()
    {
        SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        response.ContentType = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType)
                                   ? ContentType
                                   : "application/json";

        if (ContentEncoding != null)
            response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;

        if (Data != null)
        {
            var writer = new JsonTextWriter(response.Output) { Formatting = Formatting };

            JsonSerializer serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(SerializerSettings);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, Data);

            writer.Flush();
        }
    }
```

A Typical use in an action method would be:

```
public ActionResult Orders_Read([DataSourceRequest] Object request)
    {
        int count = 0;
        var ds = (DataSourceRequest)request;
        var ListOfItemsToDisplay = GetItemsWithPagingInfo
                                (
                                    MySearchParameters,
                                    ds.PageSize,
                                    ds.Page,
                                    out count
                                );
        return new JsonNetResult
                                {
                                    Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
                                    Data = new MyDataSource
                                                   {
                                                       Data = ListOfItemsToDisplay
                                                       Total = count,
                                                       AggregateResults = null,
                                                       Errors = null
                                                   }
                                    };
    }
```